# write the same format in file using nodejs fs.writeFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express, fs

Node Js when I print one variable I am getting values like this

```
    Supercluster {
          options: { log: true, radius: 60, extent: 512, maxZoom: 16 },
          trees:
           [ KDBush {
               nodeSize: 64,
               points: [Array],
               ids: [Uint16Array],
               coords: [Float32Array] },
             KDBush {
               nodeSize: 64,
               points: [Array],
               ids: [Uint16Array],
               coords: [Float32Array] },
             KDBush {
               nodeSize: 64,
               points: [Array],
               ids: [Uint16Array],
               coords: [Float32Array] }
     ]};
```

I want to write this to one file. I am using below code

```
fs.writeFile('./filename.json', json, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error writing file', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully wrote file')
    }
});
```

after execution file got created but inside file only `[object Object]`

Then I used `JSON.stringify(clusterPacked)` but my value format got changed

**Supercluster  and KDBush** all are removed and my output is like

```
{ options: { log: true, radius: 60, extent: 512, maxZoom: 16 },
  trees:
   [ { nodeSize: 64, points: [Array], ids: [Object], coords: [Object] },
     { nodeSize: 64, points: [Array], ids: [Object], coords: [Object] }
   ]
};
```

I just want to save the format as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

fs.writeFile('./filename.json', util.inspect(json), err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error writing file', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully wrote file')
    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting error
Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @NathanSrivi I have edited the answer to include the 2nd approach using ```util.inspect(...)```. Could you try that?

Comment: Sorry It is my mistake. it is working perfectly. thank you so much for this help

Comment: Last one small question how to read this stored value? normal read will work or need to do any otherthings?

Comment: @NathanSrivi Normal read with ```fs``` should work. Let me know if you run into any issues

Comment: can you please elaborate more on util.inspect? It will be helpful for me

Comment: @NathanSrivi ```util.inspect(targetObj, options)``` method simply returns a string representation of the object. You can also pass ```options``` object with properties like ```showHidden```, ```depth``` and so on as the 2nd argument. For more detailed information I would suggest you to refer the docs.

Comment: when I try to read the value from file. it is coming as a string and not able to convert into object. Please help me

Comment: Have you tried to use ```JSON.parse()``` on the string?